# AS3 making an array invisible!? how?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

```
var sunflowers30:Array = [sunflowerpetal1,sunflowerpetal2,sunflowerpetal3,sunflowerpetal4,sunflowerpetal5,sunflowerpetal6];

sunflowers30.visible = false;
```

Why is the code ***up*** there not working?? what am i doing wrong?? ( trying to make the array invisible).

also should this code not work as well? ***(below)***( trying to go to a different scene once array ( all instances) are hidden/invisible).

```
if(sunflowers30.visible == false)
{

gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace")

    }
;
```

- `Sunflowerpetal 1-6` are instances that are on my stage currently
- `Sunflowers30` is the array i made from the instances on stage.
- `"Theplace"` is the next scene

Help and comments are much appreciated I'm kind of new to AS3 and code in general but i bet you code gurus could help me out, many thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array does not have a visible property.
What you need to do is loop through the array and set the property on each element of that array.

```
var sunflowers30:Array = [sunflowerpetal1,sunflowerpetal2,sunflowerpetal3,sunflowerpetal4,sunflowerpetal5,sunflowerpetal6];


for each( var obj:Object in sunflowers30 ){
  obj.visible = false;
}




// or another way or doing it
for( var i:int = 0; i<sunflowers30.length; i++){
   obj.visible = false;
}
```

And as your second question asks if it should work the answer is no.
You are again targeting the array and not the object you want to test if it is visible.

```
if(sunflowerpetal1.visible == false)
{

gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace")

    }
;
```

Comment: hey thank you very much! now i also tried the one that you said on the second one, if(sunflowerpetal1.visible ==false){ gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace") } ; but that also had no success.. i dont understand why since sunflowerpetal1 is the instance of the movieclip on my stage

Comment: Right before the if statement try trace(sunflowerpetal1.visible) and see if is actually false

Comment: If all else fails take the if statement out and try gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace")
 directly and see if that works. If not I can't help without some error codes.

Comment: the gotAndPlay(1, "theplace") alone does work it switches my scene for some reason i just cant seem to trigger the click of the instance to take me to the next scene with the if statement, i just want it so that once all instances are invisible the scene changes, that doesnt sound too complex, or is it .. ?